# Tips and Tricks for Asking a Good Question?

Tags: discussion

Some users have problems when it comes to asking a good question and the community usually has to jump in via the comments and help them get their questions answered by providing them tips for providing a better question.

I would like to open up a discussion and hear from you what you think some good tips and tricks are related to asking a great Salesforce Stackexchange question. The goal is to hopefully link new users to a thread like this so they can hear from the community what they like to see in a question.

For some basic information to start - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, if you are a new user, read the [FAQ](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq). This site is built for specific type of questions, specifically questions that can turn into a discussion really aren't a viable question to be brought up in this format.

Second, provide as much detail as possible. If you are having a problem with a particular piece of code, post that code snippet in your question. If you are receiving a specific error, provide that error in your question. If the CSS you are using isn't displaying a field properly, take a screenshot of your page to show us what is going on. Absolutely no one on this site will punish you for posting too much information. In fact, you will more than likely find the response you desire as well as receiving more upvotes and gaining more attention.

Thirdly, this site has several built in tools to not only include this information but make it simple and easy to read. Notice that the question/answer box provides functionality for adding code ({ }), functionality for quoting a source (''), and even functionality for immediately uploading an image (the small image icon). **Use these features!** If you feel more comfortable using HTML, this site also supports that feature as well.

Finally, make sure you are polite and clear. Monitor your question and followup with anyone who responds. The community here takes time out of their day to help people. Please make sure they are given your attention when they attempt to help you.

Comment: I read "Absolutely no one on this site will punish you for posting too much information" and I could have SWORN I heard someone whisper "Challenge accepted" somewhere...  (cough)  Anyway.  Good response.  ;-)

Comment: Well too much info isn't an issue, but it's often an indicator they're asking the community to [do their homework or other code dump questions](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/351/594).  Could definitely use some tips on guiding this users to narrow down their specific issue and question instead of just "Why isn't this working?"